# How to group observations that are combinations together in SAS

Tags: sas, combinations

An example would be a data set:

```
data have;
input observations $;
datalines;
'a-b-c'
'b-c-a'
'c-a-b'
'd-e'
'e-d'
'a-b'
'a-b-c-d'
'b-a-d-c'
'a-b-c-e'
;
run;
```

I'm not sure how to get all observations that are combinations of each other to be mapped to some kind of a combo_id. example of desired data:

```
'a-b-c'    combo_1
'b-c-a'    combo_1
'c-a-b'    combo_1
'd-e'      combo_2
'e-d'      combo_2
'a-b'      combo_3
'a-b-c-d'  combo_4
'b-a-d-c'  combo_4
'a-b-c-e'  combo_5
```

at this point I'd be able to group by combo_id in sql...

Comment: Please post how you'd do it in SQL, SAS can implement SQL via PROC SQL.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
data have;
input x $20.;
cards;
a-b-c
b-c-a
c-a-b
d-e
e-d
a-b
a-b-c-d
b-a-d-c
a-b-c-e
;
run;


data want;
   set have;
   retain string grp num;
   if countw(x) ^=num then do;
        grp+1;
        string=x;
   end;
   else do;
      array var [5] $1 _temporary_;
      call missing (of var(*));
      do i=1 to countw(x);
         var(i)=scan(x,i);
      end;
   call sortc(of var(*));
   _string=catx('-',of var(*));
   if _string^=string then grp=grp+1;
   end;
   group=cats('Comb_',grp);
   num=countw(x);
   if not missing (_string) then string=_string;
   else string=x; 
   keep x group;
run;
```

Comment: This will not work if the groups are not already sorted in the input data.

Comment: I did as OP gave dummy data and desired data.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would tackle this:

First, get the maximum number of elements in the group.

```
proc sql noprint;
select max(countw(observations,"-"))
    into :max trimmed
    from have;
quit;
```

Then use a data step to sort the elements in each observation.

```
data have;
set have;
format v1-v&max $8.
       observation_new $32.;
array v[&max];

/*remove ' and count the number in the group*/
observations = strip(tranwrd(observations,"'",""));
n = countw(observations,"-");

/*Split the elements into the array*/
do i=1 to n;
    v[i] = scan(observations,i,"-");
end;

/*Sort the array*/
call sortc(of v[*]);

/*Build a new observations record with the sorted values*/
observation_new = "";
do i=1 to &max;
    if v[i] ^= "" then
        observation_new = strip(catx("-",observation_new,v[i]));
end;

drop i n v:;
run;
```

Now sort the new observation and use a Data Step to assign the combo ID

```
proc sort data=have;
by observation_new;
run;

data want;
set have;
by observation_new;
retain combo_id 0;

if first.observation_new then
    combo_id = combo_id +1;
run;
```

This gives you:

```
observations    observation_new                     combo_id

  a-b           a-b                                     1
  a-b-c         a-b-c                                   2
  b-c-a         a-b-c                                   2
  c-a-b         a-b-c                                   2
  a-b-c-d       a-b-c-d                                 3
  b-a-d-c       a-b-c-d                                 3
  a-b-c-e       a-b-c-e                                 4
  d-e           d-e                                     5
  e-d           d-e                                     5
```

Comment: awesome! that was definitely trickier than I thought it would be. Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome.  Note the answer you marked as "selected" does not work if you don't already have the groups sorted in the input data.  This answer addresses that.

Answer (score 0):

**Way 1**

With N apriori known elements in the combinatorial basis you can create a lookup table of all possible combination permutations.  The number of items in the lookup table escalates after 8, which has 109,600 (as computed by [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum(k!%20binomial(8,k),1,8)).)

The benefit is that the combination id can be applied by lookup in single pass of the data.  There is no extra manipulation of the `observation` value needed.  The approach might be best with clean large volume data.

```
%macro all_combo_perm(items=, out=, delim=-);

  %local i j N;

  data _null_;
    count = 0;
    do v = &items;
      count + 1;
    end;
    call symputx('N', count);
  run;

  data &out;
    array items(&N) $32 ( &items );

    %do i = 1 %to &N;
      array items_subset&i items1-items&i;
    %end;

    do i = 1 to &N;
      do j = 1 to comb(&N, i);
        call allcomb(j, i, of items(*));
        combo_id + 1;
        length combo_perm $100;

        do p = 1 to fact(i);
          select (i);
          %do i = 1 %to &N;
            when (&i) do; 
              call allperm(p, of items_subset&i(*));
              combo_perm = catx("&delim", of items_subset&i(*));
            end;
          %end;
          otherwise;
          end;

          output;
        end;

        if i > 1 then do; x=items[1]; items[1]=items[2]; items[2]=x; end;
      end;
    end;

    keep combo_id combo_perm;
  run;

%mend;

options mprint;

%all_combo_perm(items=%str('a','b','c','d','e'), out=combo_perms);
```

id applied via hash lookup

```
data want;
  if _n_ = 1 then do;
    if 0 then set combo_perms;
    declare hash lookup(dataset:'combo_perms', hashexp:10);
    lookup.defineKey('combo_perm');
    lookup.defineData('combo_id');
    lookup.defineDone();
  end;

  set have;
  if lookup.find(key:observation) ne 0 then combo_id = -1;

  drop combo_perm;
run;
```

**Way 2**

- Two pass approach.
- First pass determines distinct `observation` values present and computes an owning combination id.
- Second pass applies combination id by lookup or merge.

DomPazz answer shows this way.

Benefit is that it works for data on hand with no aprioris required.  Two pass could be slower for large volume data.

**Way 3**

Dynamic lookup built during pass through.

Takes Dom's split and sort method for constructing the lookup key and stores it in a lookup hash maintained during a single pass.  The detriment is the time resources used to construct the key for each row of data can become significant in large volume data.

Neat bits to understand are `call missing` to reset the parts, and `catx('-', of parts(*))` to construct the key.

```
data want_3;
  set have;

  if _n_ = 1 then do;
    length combo_id 8;
    declare hash lookup(hashexp:10);
    lookup.defineKey('observation_key');
    lookup.defineData('combo_id');
    lookup.defineDone();
    call missing (combo_id);
    observation_key = observation; * prep pdv;
  end;

  array parts (99) $32 _temporary_;  * 99 is reasonable never to be exceeded bound;
  call missing (of parts(*));

  do i = 1 to dim(parts);
    parts(i) = scan(observation,i,"-");
    if missing(parts(i)) then leave;
  end;

  if i = dim(parts) then do;
    put 'ERROR: need more part slots!';
    stop;
  end;

  call sortc(of parts[*]);
  observation_key = catx('-', of parts(*)); * catx will not concatenate missing values;

  if lookup.find() ne 0 then do;
    combo_id = lookup.num_items + 1;
    lookup.add();
  end;

  drop i observation_key;
run;
```